# A question from Sheldon Axler Section 2A Exercise 5

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question would be : $A$ is a set of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\bigcap_{F\in A}=\emptyset$. Show that if $A$ contains at least one bounded set, that there exists an integer $n$ and $F_{1},\dotso, F_{n}$ in $A$ so that $\bigcap F_{i}=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the definition of compactness, i.e., a subset $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compact if each of its open covers has a finite subcover. (See Definition 2.10 and Theorem 2.12 in the textbook.)

Suppose that $F_0\in \mathcal{A}$ is compact (closed and bounded). Since $\bigcap_{F\in \mathcal{A}}F=\emptyset$, the family $\{\mathbb{R}\setminus F:F\in \mathcal{A}\}$ is an open cover of $F_0$, which contains a finite subcover $\{\mathbb{R}\setminus F_j:1\le j\le n\}$. Now, $\{F_j:0\le j\le n\}$ is a finite collection of sets with empty intersection.

Comment: (+1) Nice solution. One minor comment, I think you meant: " Since $\bigcap_{F\in \mathcal{A}}F=\emptyset$, ...".